# How to delete a file? Getting "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, file-handling, os.path

**Update**: I am not getting the error when hosting this online. Able to delete normally. Leaving this up incase there are any useful answers for running locally on windows pc.

**Context**: I download a pdf file from discord. Then I read it etc. then I delete it.
(I am having to download and delete in first place because reading it directly from discord object was causing me to hit discord's rate limits)

What I have tried till now

1. simple os.remove()
2. f.close() then os.remove()
3. f.close() then renaming the file (with 'temp' suffix) then os.remove()
4. waiting for the lock to be removed, with asyncio and retrying (retried 100 times in a minute, still was locked)
5. deleting the folder that contains the file using shutil.rmtree()
6. changing the directory to some temp using os.chdir() then doing the operation there then changing it back to previous directory, then deleting the temp directory using shutil.rmtree

Everytime the same error
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

In some discord messages I pass multiple pdf files. It does not throw error in deleting the first one, but again throws it in last one.

Here's my code

```
filepath=os.path.join('downloaded_files', attachment.filename)
print(filepath)
with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
    input_text=pdf_text_from_attachment(filepath)
    to_send=input_text
    
    await send_message_in_thread(
                                channel_id,
                                to_send)
    f.close()
    os.remove(filepath)
```

Comment: Try removing the `f.close()` and put `os.remove(filepath)` outside of `with open(...) as f`.

Comment: I tried that also. Still error

Comment: @KJ Thanks for your input. I am writing this code for a discord bot which needs to be live 24x7(ideally), hosted on a server, so this is not feasible here.

Comment: Have you tried using an `io.BytesIO` object?  That let's you create something that looks like a file but lives in memory.

Comment: To do this reliably, your `with` statement would need to contain one line: `f.write(content)`.  Everything else would need to follow the `with`, so you are guaranteed the file has been created.

Comment: @TimRoberts I was using BytesIO earlier, but it lead me to hit discord's rate limits, thats why i started downloading and reading in first place

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
filepath=os.path.join('downloaded_files', attachment.filename)
print(filepath)
with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)

input_text=pdf_text_from_attachment(filepath)
await send_message_in_thread(channel_id, input_text)
os.remove(filepath)
```